# Just started job that may not be right fit -- how do I recover?

Tags: new-job, job-change, project-management, productivity, termination

Three months ago, I landed a new job at an industry-respected company. This position was a deviation from my career track. Throughout my career, I always felt competent in my job. In fact, any job I have ever taken, I quickly excelled at and was a valued team member. When I saw the posting for this position, I felt I was perfect for it and had a million ideas on how I could make a positive impact in the role and company.

Three months into the job the company and culture are great, but I feel completely ineffective at my job and like I accepted the wrong role. I feel like my boss and I don't speak the same language, and I feel like we always talk past each other. The one other person on the team works on his own, and my boss is in another city. Usually I'm a highly motivated, positive and effective person who takes on new challenges. but in this role I am unmotivated, procrastinating and developing a negative attitude, which I'm ashamed of.

I'd like to talk to my boss about this, but frankly I'm worried he'll agree and fire me.

What steps can I take to get things on track in this position?  How can I ask my manager for help without putting my position at risk?  Or is there some other action I can take beyond "keep trying"?

Comment: Do you meet with your manager on a regular basis?

Comment: Your question was receiving close votes because of the open-ended request for advice.  I've made an edit to focus it and make it work better on our site.  Please review and make any further edits (like answering the question in the previous comment).  Our community will review for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Talk to your boss.*

He won't fire you for coming to him with your concerns - I don't see how he could, legally.  You need to build a relationship with your boss, and you can't do that if you don't talk to him.  Unfortunately, a boss isn't like a boy/girl friend - if it's hard to communicate or "isn't clicking" you can't just give up and get a new one.  You need to work at fixing your job.

Give it another three months, and dedicate yourself to crafting the job you want.